# Custom Post Type Taxonomy Select dropdown list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I've created a select dropdown list of terms from a CPT taxonomy. This works fine. Here is my code

```
<label for="films">Films</label>
    <select name="films" id="films">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Films</option>
        <?php
            $taxonomy = 'films';
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

            if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : ?>
                <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endif;?>
     </select>
```

What I'd like to do is when you select a term from the dropdown, it then jumps to the term archive page automatically. Similar to the native WP category dropdown widget.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using JavaScript. You'll need to add an event listener that triggers a redirect to the selected URL when the dropdown's value is changed.

Here's one possible way of doing it. It's the quickest way I can think of, and I haven't tested it yet, but you get the idea. You can further improve on this by using jQuery if you want to.

```
<label for="films">Films</label>
<select name="films" id="films" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Films</option>
    <?php
        $taxonomy = 'films';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : ?>
            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endif;?>
</select>
```